# How could I setText in my activity of a textView in common layout for a ViewPager in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-viewpager, settext

Update of the code:
my problem is a nullPointerExeption on the line :

```
test.setText("try");
```

because the line

```
test=(TextView)myPager.findViewById(R.id.txtPagerDate);
```

return a null view

My code:

MainMeteo.java :

```
public class MainMeteo extends FragmentActivity {

    ViewPager myPager;
    ViewPagerAdapterBis myPagerAdapter;
    TextView test;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_meteo);
        myPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapterBis(getSupportFragmentManager());
        myPager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.panelpager);
        myPager.setAdapter(myPagerAdapter);


        test=(TextView)myPager.findViewById(R.id.txtPagerDate);
        test.setText("try");

    }

}
```

ViewAdapterBis.java:

```
    public class ViewPagerAdapterBis extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public ViewPagerAdapterBis(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        Fragment fragment = new ViewPagerAdapterObject();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        // Our object is just an integer :-P
        args.putInt(ViewPagerAdapterObject.ARG_OBJECT, i + 1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 15;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return "OBJECT " + (position + 1);
    }


}
```

ViewPagerAdapterObject.java

```
public class ViewPagerAdapterObject extends Fragment {

    public static final String ARG_OBJECT = "object";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
            ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // The last two arguments ensure LayoutParams are inflated
        // properly.
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.meteo_pager, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

And my two xml layout:

meteo_pager.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtPagerDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:text="Date az zaza"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtPagerMaxMin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtPagerDate"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:text="Max | Min"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtPagerPrecipitations"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtPagerMaxMin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:text="Précipitations"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtPagerVent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtPagerPrecipitations"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:text="Vent"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtPagerNeige"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtPagerVent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:text="Neige"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtPagerDate"
        android:src="@android:drawable/spinner_background" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

main_meteo.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    tools:context=".MainMeteo" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtPays"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtVille"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:text="Pays"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtPagerDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtPays"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Actuellement" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtPagerVent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtPagerDate"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtPagerDate"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:text="Vent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtHumidite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtPagerVent"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:text="Humidité" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtMoyenneTemps"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtVisibilite"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:text="Mostly" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtVisibilite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtcouvNuage"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:text="Visibilité" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtcouvNuage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtPrecipitation"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:text="Couv. nuage" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTemperature"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txtPagerVent"
        android:text="x°"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtRessentie"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtTemperature"
        android:text="Ressentie"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtPrecipitation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtHumidite"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:text="Precipitation" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtVille"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:text="Ville"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtPagerMaxMin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtMoyenneTemps"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="15 prochains jours" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/panelpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtPagerMaxMin" >

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/txtPagerMaxMin"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtRessentie"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtRessentie"
        android:src="@android:drawable/progress_indeterminate_horizontal" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

If you need more information, just ask me.

the first question before update :

http://www.sendspace.com/file/npf0q8

Comment: Are you sure that playerXName is definitely declared in your activity_main?  Or do you have another layout file?

Comment: I have two layout : activity_main with a title, and page_test with different TextView. it's page_test who feed my page viewer and playerXName is declared in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to get a view that is declared in a layout that is not the contentView that was set (activity_main).

You can try inflating the View for your page_test and grab your textview that way, like so:

```
LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.meteo_pager, null);
test = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtPagerDate);
test.setText("try");
```

Comment: I try with that:
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page_test, myPager , false); but don't work (not sure what you would say with "containerRef" but it's the only GroupView I found)>Result nullpointerExeption at this line.

Comment: try just findViewById(R.id.page_test)...and clean your project

Comment: page_test is a layout not an id,
i try with that so:  
inflater=(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page_test, null);

i don't have a force close but my TextView don't change (i've tried with only
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page_test, null); but it's make a nullPointerException).

Comment: can you post your layout files?

Comment: Also, can you confirm via the debugger that it is in fact the teamXTextView that is null and not something else on that line?

Comment: Yes, when i do a sys.out of originalValues.get(myPager.getCurrentItem()+1).get(KEY_NAME).toString()
log cat return the value "Messi"

Comment: I've tried with
 View v = myPager.findViewWithTag(myPager.getCurrentItem());
but do the same error

Comment: Ok-I would suggest that instead of trying to run this all in your main activity that you should be returning fragments with your pager.  See the example code in the tutorial http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/index.html

Comment: I will try and run your code when I get a chance but in the meantime check out that tutorial to see a good way of implementing your pager navigation.

Comment: Hum, I've the same problem, i don't now how to get my view to change the text (but the slide worked good). I update my code with the code i use for my app (not the test code).

Comment: So you got past the NullPointerException?

Comment: no, i have again the nullPointerException when i try to change the text.

Comment: i tried with: View v=myPager.getChildAt(0);,    View v= myPager.findViewWithTag(1);,  View v= myPager.findFocus();,  test=(TextView)myPager.findViewById(R.id.txtPagerDate);,
  View v=myPager.findViewWithTag(myPager.getTag()); and  View v=myPager.findViewWithTag(myPager.getCurrentItem());

Comment: Earest, I got your code working on my machine.  All I added was the following to MainMeteo...LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.meteo_pager, null);
        test = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtPagerDate);
        test.setText("try");

Comment: I also edited my answer above to reflect this.  Let me know how it goes!  Also, be sure you are importing the android.support.v4..packages for your fragments and such

Answer (score 0):

That the views all use the same layout should not be a problem. If you're using a `ViewPager` you should be able to get the `View` being displayed (or the one you want) and then modify the value of a `TextView` calling `findViewById` on that specific view. For example, to change a `TextView` within the view that is currently being displayed:

Get the view that has the TextView you want to change

```
View v = MainActivity.myPager.getChildAt(position) //position = index of view in pager
```

Find the TextView you want from within that view

```
TextView nameToChange = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
```

Then you should be able to change the text using

```
nameToChange.setText(newName);
```

Comment: It's dont work, if i do this modification i don't see my Sys.out.println("Elephant"); that I saw before.
i've tried with :
     View v = MainActivity.myPager.getChildAt(position), 
     View v = MainActivity.this.myPager.getChildAt(position) and 
     View v = this.myPager.getChildAt(position)